# how to solve no attribute 'routes' in fastapi?

Tags: fastapi

I followed https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/ resource to design my app

```
.....game/urls.py....

from fastapi import APIRouter
router = APIRouter()
@router.post("/", response_model=schemas.GameOut, tags=["games"])
def create_game(game: schemas.GameIn, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return Crud.create(db,game,model)

...main.py...

from game import urls as game_urls
app.include_router(game_urls,prefix="/games")
```

imported everything properly. 
When i run uvicorn main:app --reload it is showing "NO attribures 'routes' " error
I am not able to find, what is the mistake i am doing here. Could any one helps me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you're injecting the entire urls module in your last line;

```
app.include_router(game_urls, prefix="/games")
                   ^
```

I believe you should only inject the router object, e.g. (you might want to import just the router here instead)

```
app.include_router(game_urls.router, prefix="/games")
```

Comment: Thankyou. yes i missed that. I added router to game_url. It's working

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have issue with @router not existing make sure you define the APIRouter as router and not web_router = APIRouter()